# Is there a flaw in how clang implements char8_t or does some dark corner of the standard prohibit optimization?

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-optimization, c++20

clang 8.0.0 introduces support for the `char8_t` type from c++20. However, I would expect the following functions to have the same compiler output

```
#include <algorithm>

bool compare4(char const* pcha, char const* pchB, int n) {
    return std::equal(pcha, pcha+4, pchB);
}

bool compare4(char8_t const* pchA, char8_t const* pchB, int n) {
    return std::equal(pchA, pchA+4, pchB);
}
```

However, they [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/8xkBs0) under `-std=c++2a -O2` to

```
compare4(char const*, char const*, int):   # @compare4(char const*, char const*, int)
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        cmp     eax, dword ptr [rsi]
        sete    al
        ret
_Z8compare4PKDuS0_i:                       # @_Z8compare4PKDuS0_i
        mov     al, byte ptr [rdi]
        cmp     al, byte ptr [rsi]
        jne     .LBB1_4
        mov     al, byte ptr [rdi + 1]
        cmp     al, byte ptr [rsi + 1]
        jne     .LBB1_4
        mov     al, byte ptr [rdi + 2]
        cmp     al, byte ptr [rsi + 2]
        jne     .LBB1_4
        mov     al, byte ptr [rdi + 3]
        cmp     al, byte ptr [rsi + 3]
        sete    al
        ret
.LBB1_4:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

in which the latter is clearly less optimized.
Is there a reason for this (I couldn't find any in the standard) or is this a bug in clang?

Comment: Looks like a flaw/missing optimization.  GCC produces the same code for both functions.

Comment: Do note that `char8_t` [is actually a `unsigned char`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.types#basic.fundamental-9), but even making that change to the first function the compiler still optimizes the code so it can't be that: https://godbolt.org/z/uUhMkW

Comment: I have a suspicion that it might have to do with the fact that char8_t is a library-provided type which compiler has no intrinsic understanding of.

Comment: Not completely related, but interesting nonetheless: Adding `-stdlib=libc++` to the compile options in godbolt _have_ the same compiler output, however in the less optimized way (it seems like godbolt uses `libstdc++` by default). See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/-XxPMu). So apparently the standard library version seems to matter as well

Comment: @SergeyA Is it considered a library type?  It is defined in [basic.types]

Comment: Note also the [author's comment](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=331244): _"This implementation is experimental, and will be removed or revised
substantially to match the proposal as it makes its way through the C++
committee."_

Comment: @NathanOliver I do not think standard has any mandate on how exactly the type is defined, am I wrong?

Comment: @SergeyA It calls it out specifically [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.types#basic.fundamental-9)

Comment: @NathanOliver but I can't find any requirement for the type to be specified here or there. For example, point 11 talks about other types together with this char8_t type, and those are specified in stdint.h

Comment: @SergeyA: I don't know what "library-defined type" would mean in this case. It must be a fundamental type, because that's what the standard says. And you never have to include a header to use it, because the standard never says that it lives in any header. It might be implemented as a "library type" on some implementation by including a magical header, but as far as a *user* is concerned, it should appear just like `char16_t` or `int` or any other fundamental type.

Comment: @NicolBolas what I meant is that the type itself is defined in the header file (may be the one compiler always includes). And when it comes to optimizations, it is conceivable that compilers do not have intrinsic knowledge of the types defined in this magic header file. And the question is about optimizations.

Comment: `std::equal` is usually optimized to use `memcmp` if possible. Maybe this optimization is yet to be added for `char8_t`.

Comment: It's surprising for me that the same highly suboptimal code is emitted for [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Umdgkk) by all major compilers (at least it is highly suboptimal if the result is true).

Comment: I suspect that this has more to do with libstdc++ (which the godbolt link is using) rather than clang. If you switch to libc++, then both of the disassemblies are the same (like the second one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In libstdc++, `std::equal` calls `__builtin_memcmp` when it detects that the arguments are "simple", otherwise it uses a naive for loop. "Simple" here means pointers (or certain iterator wrappers around pointer) to the same integer or pointer type.([relevant source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-8_2_0-release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h#L792-L832))

   - Whether a type is an integer type is detected by the internal `__is_integer` trait, but libstdc++ 8.2.0 (the version used on godbolt.org) does not specialize this trait for `char8_t`, so the latter is not detected as an integer type.([relevant source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-8_2_0-release/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/cpp_type_traits.h#L123-L273))
2. Clang (with this particular configuration) generates more verbose assembly in the for loop case than in the `__builtin_memcmp` case. <del>(But the former is not necessarily less optimized in terms of performance. See [Loop_unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling).)</del>

So there's a reason for this difference, and it's not a bug in clang IMO.

Comment: I completely agree with your first point, thanks for pointing out the relevant source code! But I don't agree with your second point: The short assembly is comparing four bytes in a single instruction, so that is even more *loop-unrolled* than the simple unrolling from the verbose assembly.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a "bug" in Clang; merely a missed opportunity for optimization.

You can [replicate the Clang compiler output](https://godbolt.org/z/9fCYtA) by using the same function taking an `enum class` whose underlying type is `unsigned char`. By contrast, GCC recognizes a difference between an enumerator with an underlying type of `unsigned char` and `char8_t`. It emits the same code for `unsigned char` and `char8_t`, but emits more complex code for the `enum class` case.

So something about Clang's implementation of `char8_t` seems to think of it more as a user-defined enumeration than as a fundamental type. It's best to just consider it an early implementation of the standard.

It should be noted that one of the most important differences between `unsigned char` and `char8_t` is aliasing requirements. `unsigned char` pointers may alias with pretty much anything else. By contrast, `char8_t` pointers cannot. As such, it is reasonable to expect (on a *mature* implementation, not something that beats the standard it implements to market) different code to be emitted in different cases. The trick is that `char8_t` code ought to be *more* efficient if it's different, since the compiler no longer has to emit code that performs additional work to deal with potential aliasing from stores.

Comment: I don't think aliasing can affect `std::equal` in any way.